# Is there a way to add custom attributes to the Admin side product search?

Tags: magento-1.7, catalogsearch

I am looking to be able to search by a custom attribute's values on the Admin side in Catalog > Product search.

By default you can search by a range of product ID's, name, type, attribute set name, SKU, etc.

Is there a way to add my own attribute in that product search?

Answer (score 2):

To add an attribute column to products grid you have to create a module with 2 observers.

First you have to observe `eav_collection_abstract_load_before` event and to add your attribute to collection:

```
public function eavCollectionAbstractLoadBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $observer->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('color');
}
```

Then you have to observe `adminhtml_block_html_before` event, check that the current grid is products listing and add new column:

```
public function adminhtmlBlockHtmlBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getBlock();
    if ($block->getId() == 'productGrid') {
        $block->addColumn('test', array(
            'header'    => 'Color',
            'index'     => 'color'
        ));
    }
}
```

That's all. Enjoy.

Comment: Thank you for this!  I ended up finding a work around using the SKU to be able to filter products as I need them to be.  But I'm sure I will have to use this eventually and when I do, I'll see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

This extension actually allows you to do exactly that, and it's free: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-admin-product-grid.html

Comment: Doesn't seem to be compatible with 1.7

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah read the first comment on Magento Connect, it fixes your issue :)

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I am not looking for an extension to solve this problem since I have had some bad experiences with extensions in the past.  Sometimes they are difficult to uninstall.