# Get Grid Filter in Observer

Tags: grid, filter, product-collection, filterable-attributes

How do I retrieve the grid filters in an observer?

```
public function beforeCollectionLoad(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getCollection();

    if (!isset($collection)) {
        return;
    }

    //get filter here
    //normally:
    //$filter = $this->getParam($this->getVarNameFilter(), null);
}
```

Comment: which observer are you using?

Comment: eav_collection_abstract_load_before

Answer (score 2):

when you have a grid object you can retrieve the filter array like this :

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('GridId');
    $this->setTemplate('../../..phtml');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
    $this->setVarNameFilter('_filter'); 
}

$filter = $this->getParam('_filter');
$filter_data = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->prepareFilterString($filter);                   
print_r($filter_data);
```

From a column, it's possible like this :

```
$filter = $this->getColumn()->getGrid()->getParam('_filter');
$filter_data = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->prepareFilterString($filter);                   
print_r($filter_data);
```

For the observer, you can do [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/5031/24398)

Hope this help